# What is wrong with my inductive Proof

Tags: discrete-mathematics, induction

Claim: For all integers ∀n ≥ 0, 3n = 0.
Proof: By strong induction on n. For the base case, we have
n = 0. Since 3 · 0 = 0, the claim holds for the base case.
For the inductive step, we prove the property for k + 1, i.e. that
3(k + 1) = 0.
Observe that k+1 can be written as i+j for some natural numbers
i, j where i ≤ k and j ≤ k. Now, by the inductive hypothesis, we
have 3i = 0 and 3j = 0. Hence, 3 · (k + 1) = 3i + 3j = 0 + 0 = 0.
Hence the property holds.

Could someone tell me whats wrong with my proof?

Comment: Can $0+1$ be written as $i+j$ where $i\le 0$ and $j\le 0$?

Comment: "Observe that k+1 can be written as i+j for some natural numbers i, j where i ≤ k and j ≤ k."  uh.... no, it can't.

Comment: $k+1 = i + j$ where $i\le k$ and $j\le k$ implies $k-i=j-1$.  As $i\le k$ then $0\le k-1 = j-1$ and that implies $j\ge 1$.  But that is a contradiction of $j\le k$ if $k < 1$.  So your statement "for all natural numbers $k+1$ can be written as $k+1 = j+i$ where $j\le k$ and $i\le k$" is just plain wrong.

Comment: Actually the linked to file that this is a dupe has a *slightly* different error.  The other post doesn't assume that $k+1=i+j; i,j \le k$ (which is not possible if $k=0$) but that $k+1=i+j; i,j\le k+1$ which *is* always possible.  But later without explicitly stating so, the post assumes that $i$ and $j$ are both *strictly* less than $k+1$ whereas it had only been assumed they were less than or equal to $k+1$.  $k+1=1$ can be written as $i+j; i,j\le 1$ but one of the $i$ or $j$ *must* be equal to $1$ and $k+1=1=i+j; i,j<1$ is impossible.

Answer (score 0):

Your analysis is faulty.  $(0 + 1)$ can not be written as $i + j$, where $i,j \leq 0.$